# PHP Easier way to get unique in array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-unique

I have been racking my head trying to think if there is a simpler method to grabbing the unique objects out of an array, but can't find any documentation or confirmation that anything exists that will do what I am asking.

I have an API returning the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Name] => Kory Kelly
            [PhoneNumber] => (555) 555-5555
            [EmailAddress] => kkelly@email.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Name] => Kory Kelly
            [PhoneNumber] => (555) 555-5555
            [EmailAddress] => kkelly@email.com
        )

)
```

Now obviously I cannot use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) -- Since it checks actual values against array keys --  I have built a recursive function to tear apart the objects, rebuild as an array and do the checks manually during rebuild IE

```
if ( $arr['Name'] === $passed_arr['Name']
    && $arr['PhoneNumber'] === $passed_arr['PhoneNumber']
    && $arr['EmailAddress'] === $passed_arr['EmailAddress'] )
```

And that works .. But it seems a little long winded.  Is there a built-in / more efficient approach to this?  I feel like I am re-inventing the wheel with my current aproach.

Comment: how about using json_encode?

Comment: @nicael can you eleborate?  The array of objects is just decoded JSON ..  That's the exact output after decoding it.

Comment: your task is to de-duplicate array of objects, right?

Comment: to compare 2 objects, you can json_encode them and compare results

Comment: Single if instead of 3 `&&` s -- Now I get where you're going with that! -- OR at that point I can use `array_unique` -- Even better

Comment: @nicael -- That was a great solution .. Just built an array of JSON strings and THEN used `array_unique` .. Works like a charm ..  Please answer and I will accept.

Comment: You could use `(array)$arr == (array)$passed_arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON string of the objects is used as a key, this can also be implemented with a simple foreach loop.

```
$arr = [
  (object)['Name' => 'Kory Kelly', 'PhoneNumber' => '(555) 555-5555'],
  (object)['Name' => 'Kory Kelly', 'PhoneNumber' => '(555) 555-5555'],
  (object)['Name' => 'Kory Kelly', 'PhoneNumber' => '(555) 555-5555X'],  //different
];

foreach($arr as $key => $object){
  $arr[json_encode($object)] = $object;
  unset($arr[$key]);
}
$arr = array_values($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Try it yourself at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/amGMJ).

Compared to array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR ), this approach only becomes interesting if only certain keys are to be taken into account in the object comparison.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to check the data type, then you can use `array_unique()` with the flag `SORT_REGULAR` for unique objects

```
$list = json_decode('[{
  "name": "Ahmed",
  "phone": "(555) 555-5555",
  "email" : "test@test.com"
},
{
  "name": "Ahmed",
  "phone": "(555) 555-5555",
  "email" : "test@test.com"
},
{
  "name": "Ahmed",
  "phone": "(555) 555-5555",
  "email" : "test1@test.com"
}
]');

$uniqueList = array_unique($list, SORT_REGULAR );
```

the result should be

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1047 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Ahmed"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(14) "(555) 555-5555"
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test@test.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#1045 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Ahmed"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(14) "(555) 555-5555"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "test1@test.com"
  }
}
```

I hope it's useful

Comment: Works. If the keys are to be renumbered, an array_values($uniqueList) can be used.